# Perform Zoom Out/In in Selenium using Javascript package

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I want to perform Zoom out/In with Selenium tool having Javascript package

All solutions available on internet are in respect to Java.
Please Note: document. and JavascriptExecutor does not work

Comment: Can we see _document. and JavascriptExecutor does not work_ and the error that you got ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.